# Azure key vault in logic app to encrypt or decrypt files

Tags: azure, encryption, azure-logic-apps, azure-keyvault

I have a case were I need to connect to a Bank using sFTP and retrieve bank statements and send payment files.

**The basic flows will be:**

**Get Bank statements.**

- Fetch Encrypted Signed Data from Bank.
- Decrypt Encrypted Signed Data with my private key.
- Verify the Plain text signed file.
- Unzip data file for further processing.
- List item

**Send Payment File**

- Naming Give payment file the right filename.
- Compress Zip data file (PKZIP format).
- Sign zipped data file with your private key and hash algorithm SHA2-256.
- Encrypt the signed data file with AES256.
- Send Encrypted Signed Data.

Checking the requirements received against the Key Vault functionalities is see that
Encryption algorithm for data **AES256** is not supported?

Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As of now algorithms supported for encryption or decryption using logic apps are   **RSA-OAEP**, **RSA1_5** and **RSA-OAEP-256**.
ASE algorithm is not available from logic apps.

Refer this [link](https://dev.to/425show/encryptdecrypt-data-with-net-6-and-azure-key-vault-oak) it may help you

[image]

[image]